# Initializing angular controller variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

I am having an issue where my controller variables are not being initialized correctly as per the controller code.

The controller code is

```
  angular.module('test')
  .controller('RegisterCtrl', function RegisterCtrl($scope) {
var vm = this;
   vm.model = {companyName:'aaa'};
    vm.data= [{fieldtype: 'input',key:'companyName'}]; 
});
```

The ui-router is

```
  .state('register', {
        //     abstract: true,
        url: "/register",
        templateUrl: "/views/register.html",
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl',
        controlleras: 'vm'
      })
```

I have a verify basic html to show the output of model:

```
<h2>Model</h2>
<pre>{{vm.model }}</pre>
```

When debugging the code in chrome it passes through the controller code and sets both model and data correctly, but when the page has finished loading  the vm.model is blank.I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The state configuration object for [`ui-router`](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) does not have a `controlleras` property. You need to specify it in your `controller` property instead (i.e. `controller: 'RegisterCtrl as vm'`).

Comment: @miqid actually, it does, but it's case sensitive.  it is `controllerAs`.  This is a simple typo.

Comment: @Claies, my bad! Indeed it does. Only two table rows down in the documentation too. :-(

Comment: Yes it was case sensitive and now works.....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your HTML body tag:

```
<body ng-controller="RegisterCtrl as vm" ng-app="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **var**, I would advice you to use **$scope.model**, for this purpose

```
angular.module('test')
 .controller('RegisterCtrl',['$scope',function($scope) {
   $scope.model = {
                    companyName:'aaa'
                  };
   $scope.data= [
                 {
                   fieldtype: 'input',
                   key:'companyName'
                 }
                ]; 
 }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Model</h2>
<pre ng-bind="model.companyName"></pre>
<pre>{{model.companyName}}</pre>
<pre>{{model}}</pre>
```